# Trying to get a flash game onto my webpage

Tags: actionscript-3

I created a game in as3 in FlashDevelop IDE. I have my own webspace, but I'm a rookie in the sense I've never put a game on it before.  I currently have a .as3proj file and a bunch of .as and .png files. What steps would I take here? I know it will involve embedding it in html, but I have no idea what to embed or how/what that entails.

Answer (score 0):

When you compile your project in Flash Develop, you have a bin folder containing a html file and a swf file. You need to transfert the content of the bin folder and every assets loaded at runtime (images, xml, mp3, ... ).

Can you post your directory structure for more help?

Comment: You mean add them to my webpage? Would I then have to embed the .swf file into the .html file of my webpage? I apologize you'll have to bear with me here.

Comment: Sure. In my project folder I have the .as3proj file, bin, obj, and src. src contains all of the relevant .as and .png files. bin contains the .swf file , the .html file, and folder js. obj has nothing relevant afaik.

Comment: You need to embed the SWF to your webpage, you can check the index.html file source in the bin directory to view how to do. You don't need to transfert the as3proj and the as3 files on your webhosting.

Answer (score 0):

At the bare minimum, there should be a swf file in there that you need to deploy.  This is the equivalent of an exe.  Do not deploy .as files, as3proj files, or anything else like that.  As for pngs, only do so if you do not have them embedded directly into the swf (this would at least generally involve the `Embed` tag being placed above non-local variable declarations).  Make sure the path the swf is using to access the pngs, mp3s, and whatever else will still be valid once you deploy it and those files.

If you use code like:

```
[Embed(source = "plane.png")]
private const PLAYER:Class;
```

for every picture, you're embedding them, so you don't need to deploy them. If you weren't embedding them though, you'd just be linking to them. If you're linking over the Internet, just use a public URL to access those pngs, not a private, internal IP or `localhost` or anything like that. If you own the pngs and can copy them onsite, you would probably want to use a relative path. If the path to your pngs when running out of your IDE is `assets/images/<png file>`, go ahead and use that relative path, then wherever your swf is located on the server, make sure the pngs are in `<swf's folder>/assets/images`.

You do not necessarily have to embed the swf; it can act as its own webpage.  This is not smart though, in many situations.  The main reason is cache-busting.  Also you may wish to use JavaScript to do things like detect whether the person has an enabled, valid Flash Player.

There are two open-source js files that help with embedding your swf: `AC_OETags.js` and `functions.js`.  Use them.  As a matter of fact, I believe Flex/Flash builder will build an HTML or ASP file that embeds the swf, with the help of these files.  Just remember to put cache-busting meta tags into that file, so that you can immediately change the swf later.

Comment: I believe I am embedding the .pngs directly into the swf, if I'm understanding correctly. For example, I do [Embed(source = "plane.png")] private const PLAYER:Class; for every picture I use. Is this what you meant? Also, this may be a stupid question, but how would i make sure the path the .swf is using to access the .pngs will still be valid?